# How to break line after certain character in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a field that contains something like:

```
<div class="break-field">    
Something something, else else
</div>
```

So Javascript would kick in when it detects the comma in the field ',' and adds <\ br> after it, so you get something like:

```
<div class="break-field">
Something something,</ br>
else else
</div>
```

Comment: `.replace(',', ',<br>')`? it's just a string, basically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var ele = document.querySelector('.break-field');

ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ',<br/>')
```

```html
<div class="break-field">
  Something something, else else
</div>
```

---

**FYI :** Since it recreating all elements it would destroy any handler attached to the child element.

---

**UPDATE :** If multiple div needs to be updated then you need to get all and  iterate over them.

```js
// get all divs
var eles = document.querySelectorAll('.break-field');

// convert to array(or use Array.from) and iterate over them
[].slice.call(eles).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ',<br/>')
});
```

```html
<div class="break-field">
  Something something, else else
</div>
<div class="break-field">
  Something something, else else
</div>
<div class="break-field">
  Something something, else else
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. But this works only on the first <div class="break-field">, it doesn't apply on the next one.